# How do you display an image that has been saved using md5 hashed value outside of web root?

Tags: php, html, md5, md5-file

I have a series of images I wish to display on a site using the HTML img tag.

```
e.g. <img src='some/location' />
```

However the image is located in a different directory outside of the web root. (but still on same server).

Moreover it has been saved as a hashed value using php's md5_file()

How do I go about displaying the image on the site, even if I can get to the file somehow, it has been saved differently?

Comment: You can't if you hashed the contents of the file as an MD5 hash... Did you mean the file name was saved as an md5 hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do something like `<img src="image.php?img=whatever">`. Your image.php file will need to grab the image outside of the web root, as well as decode it for viewing.

You can force a .jpg (or whatever) extension using URL rewrites.